# Question regarding inequalities and probability.

Tags: probability-theory

I was doing a problem involving standard normal random variables where the solution involved this particular step:
$P\{a<X<b\}=P\{X<b\}-P\{X\le a\}$

I haven't been able to find out as to why one can do this. Can anyone explain?

Comment: This is because of lot of stats tables are cumulative. So $P(X<b)$ is counted from "zero" to $b$ and similar $P(X<a)$ is counted from "zero" to $a$. So you are essentially subtracting the smaller area from the larger area to get the "inbetween" area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $p(x)$ is the probability density function of the RV $X$, then the probabilities are given by

$$P\{a<X<b\}=\int_{a}^{b}p(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^bp(x)dx -\int_{-\infty}^{a}p(x)dx
=P\{X<b\}-P\{X< a\}$$

Answer (score 0):

the LHS implies $X \in (a,b)$ and the RHS means $X \in (-\infty,b) - (-\infty,a] = (a,b)$, and they are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

$$P(a < X <b) = \int_a^b f(x)dx = F(a) - F(a)$$
$$P(X< b) = \int_{-\infty}^bf(x)dx = F(b) - F(-\infty)$$
$$P(X < a) = \int_{-\infty}^af(x)dx = F(a) -F(-\infty)$$
With $f(x)$ some density function.

Answer (score 0):

Write
\begin{align}
   P[ X < b]
&= P[(X< b) \cap (X \leq a)] + P[(X < b)\cap(X > a)] \\
&= P[X \leq a] + P[a < X < b]
\end{align}
then subtract $P[X \leq a]$ from both sides.